# View subclass naming conventions - Android

Tags: android, naming-conventions

I am developing a *library* of custom Android `View`s that extend the abilities of existing `View`s. I have noticed that some examples of this will name their class by appending *Ex* on the end of the class name, such as [AsyncTaskEx](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-task/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/task/AsyncTaskEx.java), TextViewEx, etc. Is this a convention that [Android] developers often follow, or is there really no pattern other than personal preference?

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly legitimate question about software development.

Comment: No pattern, even in Android.  Contra to AsyncTaskEx, how about EditText, which extends TextView, which extends View, which extends Object. Personally I prefer to give them meaningful names, hence the current view I'm working on is GlobeSurfaceView. PS.  I agree with the stupid downvote comment.  +1 to help to restore the natural balance of the Androidverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put name of the parent class at the end of new, for example

`public class YellowTextView extends TextView ...`

And let IDE do other work like Content Assist, etc.

Comment: This is not what I am asking. I know how to create a subclass. This is about naming conventions, not about how to write the code itself.

Comment: Take a look at Android's documentation: `AutoCompleteTextView` -> `TextView` -> `View`